# using beautiful soup to get consolidated data from a list of urls instead of just the first url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying get the data of three states, based on the same url format.

```
states = ['123', '124', '125']

urls = []
for state in states:
    url = f'www.something.com/geo={state}'
    urls.append(url)
```

and from there I have three separate urls, each containing different state ID.

However when I get to processing it via BS, the output only showed data from the state 123.

```
for url in urls:
    client = ScrapingBeeClient(api_key="API_KEY")
    response = client.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

subsequently I extracted the columns I wanted using this:

```
listings = doc.select('.is-9-desktop')

rows = []

for listing in listings:
    row = {}
    try:
        row['name'] = listing.select_one('.result-title').text.strip()
    except:
        print("no name")
    try:
        row['add'] = listing.select_one('.address-text').text.strip()
    except:
        print("no add")
    try:
        row['mention'] = listing.select_one('.review-mention-block').text.strip()
    except:
        pass
    
    rows.append(row)
```

But as mentioned it only showed data for state 123. Hugely appreciate it if anyone could let me know where I went wrong, thank you!

### EDIT

I added the URL output into a list, and was able to get the data for all three states.

```
doc = []
for url in urls:
    client = ScrapingBeeClient(api_key="API_KEY")
    response = client.get(url)
    docs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    doc.append(docs)
```

However when I ran it through BS it resulted in the error message:

> Attribute Error: 'list' object has no attribute select.

Do I run it through another loop?

Comment: `rows=[]` should be at first when you iterate through list of urls

Comment: `url = f'www.something.com/geo={states}'` should be `url = f'www.something.com/geo={state}'`

Comment: @The_spider both look the same to me!

Comment: states is changed into state

Comment: @BhavyaParikh sorry I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: @The_spider oh okay, thank you! but it still returns the data for the first URL only

Comment: from the code it's not clear if the indentation is correct. The listings loop needs to be indented within urls loop.

Comment: you're resetting rows every time using `rows=[]`. It should be outside of your loop.

Comment: @The_spider but isn't it outside of my loop, since `for listing in listings:` is the line of code after `rows = []`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not need all of these loops - Just iterate over the states and get the listings to append to rows.

The most important thing is that `rows=[]` is placed outside the for loops to stop it overwriting itself.

#### Example

```
states = ['123', '124', '125']

rows = []

for state in states:
    url = f'www.something.com/geo={states}'
    client = ScrapingBeeClient(api_key="API_KEY")
    response = client.get(url)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    listings = doc.select('.is-9-desktop')

    for listing in listings:
        row = {}
        try:
            row['name'] = listing.select_one('.result-title').text.strip()
        except:
            print("no name")
        try:
            row['add'] = listing.select_one('.address-text').text.strip()
        except:
            print("no add")
        try:
            row['mention'] = listing.select_one('.review-mention-block').text.strip()
        except:
            pass

        rows.append(row)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I struggled with this so much I could cry. Thank you!!